# How to Accomplish App Version Switching Using Buildout?

Tags: python, virtualenv, buildout, gunicorn, supervisord

My application is developed with Flask and uses buildout to handle dependency isolation. I plan to use Gunicorn and supervisord as wsgi container and process manager, in front of which there is Nginx doing load balancing. Here is the problem when deploying a new version of the application: everything is builtout in a subfolder, how to restart the gunicorn server so that the version switching can take place gracefully?

I come up with some solutions of course:

1. Ditch gunicorn and superviosrd, and turn to apache mod_wsgi, so when deploying a new version I could simply change the folder in .wsgi file and the server will restart.
2. Use virtualenv and install gunicorn, supervisord, as well as my application package in it, so when switching version I just restart it using supervisorctl.

Is there a 'pure' buildout way that can accomplish this situation? Or any in-use production solutions will all be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just send `HUP` to gunicorn. Isn't that the gunicorn equivalent of `touch`ing the wsgi file for a `mod_wsgi` deployment?

Comment: @kojiro Gunicorn is not installed globally. Every released package has its own gunicorn and supervisord. That's the trick I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with your point-mod_wsgi-at-a-different-folder solution, you can do the same with gunicorn/buildout. Just set up your latest buildout in a different directory, stop the old gunicorn and start the new.

There'll be a short delay between stopping the one and starting the other, of course.

Alternative: set up the new one with a different port number, change the nginx config and kick ngnix if you really want zero downtime-seconds.